# Company wants me to handle most financial burdens as an expat

Tags: job-offer, contracts, legal, expenses, accommodation

I have been able to land a job in a company located in Belgium recently and it is worthwhile to mention, I do not reside in Europe.

During my application process, I was asked to pay for my paperwork in Belgium. Mind you, this is the money the company has to pay to their government (not sure exactly what sector) to get my work permit and not the "handling fee" that I need to pay to their embassy here in my home country. I refused to pay that amount since it sounded quite weird to me that I should be the one who has to pay for what seems to be their responsibility as the hiring company. This eventually led to them paying the amount themselves.

Now, it comes to the point that I need to tell their embassy where I will be staying upon my arrival.
Since I had no clue, I asked about it from my point of contact in that company. To my surprise, I was told that I could book a hotel or some other place and pass it on to the embassy and after a while look for a permanent place.

Unfortunately, since I was thinking these are implied rules (especially for expats), I never brought them up during my interview. There were a couple of things we discussed, like getting a bike and that having a car (which they were going to provide) is kind of more expensive there and the headaches associated with it. They also mentioned they would pay my water, electricity and internet bills.
Funnily enough, in my contract they have put that "I refrain from having a company car" but there is no reference to the bills they promised to take care of.

Maybe the next thing they ask me would be to get the plane ticket myself as well.

This seems like a good opportunity for me to get exposed to the market in Europe and to expand my skillset to hopefully land better jobs but the behavior of this company is kind of throwing me off.

Summary:

- Company is wanting me to handle and pay for my accommodation before arrival as an expat.
- I have worked abroad before and most things like; car, accommodation, fuel, etc... were actually handled by that company.
- It seems the things they ask me to pay and also the clauses in my contract are very one-sided in their favor.

Questions:

- Is this legal?
- Is accommodation not something that they have to take care of, at least for the initial month?

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but if it was me I would just laugh and walk off.  As you already know from your experience, companies generally pay for relocation, etc.

Comment: It is not easy to land jobs for us in Europe and this was done with so much effort. The only reason I am not walking of is the fact that they can be a good gateway for me to a better company.

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth having a conversation with them to clarify the understanding? I would think that if a company is recruiting from overseas, it is commonsense that they are going to have to handle the initial setup (or provide a generous account for relocation expenses), but it may be worth having a reality check with them.

Comment: I know right! Commonsense it is. I have sent them an email about it and am waiting to see what they come up with. However, they are beaming some scary vibes so far with the way they want me to handle what seems to be their responsibility.

Comment: Maybe they underestimate the effort for someone to relocate to Europe. Is it a large or a small company? Do they have many employees who migrated to Europe?

Comment: Does the job require to drive around? Why else would they provide a car?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler > Company cars are a huge thing here in Belgium. More than 20% of all cars registered in Belgium are company cars. Company cars are broadly given as an advantage, usually to office workers even at starting level. It's for example very hard to hire IT profiles if you don't offer that, as it's so common.

Comment: I can not really discuss what is usual/legal for relocating here in Belgium, but 1 advice that is valid for any work agreement is to have everything stated clearly in written and signed by both parties before engaging into anything... You seem keen on "investing" some money in your possible future career in Belgium/Europe, that doesn't mean you should get exploited to the bone by some shady company.

Comment: @LaurentS. - I had no idea about "company car" aspect in Belgium!  Great info !!

Comment: "Is accommodation not something that they have to take care of? at least for the initial month?" Why do you think that they should be covering it?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul Probably because it's normal.

Comment: @DJClayworth Normal where though?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul In all the countries I've worked in.

Comment: @DJClayworth great, and how does that help to clarify ops question?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul It's an answer to your question.

Comment: @PoJam, Don't let the sunk cost fallacy affect your decisions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_cost#Fallacy_effect Also, do not be too desperate. If you show too much desperation, that's a potential sign for the company to take advantage of you even more.  Talk to the company. Have them pay for accomodations for at least the first month, or at least for the first couple of weeks after your arrival. Have them pay for your plane ticket also. This is a totally normal thing to ask. And if they don't want you to have a car, make sure your commute can be done with public transportation.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I hear the public transportation there is good. so no issues in that regard. I will communicate on the points you mentioned with them. thank you!

Comment: @BernhardDöbler small company

Answer (score 6):

I am not a lawyer but I have worked in different countries in Europe. I would say that it is not illegal for them to not pay your accommodation.

There jobs that offer a relocation package that may include it, there are others that offer benefits that include cars, fuel, bills, extra holidays, courses, etc.

It is up to you to see the package, negotiate with the company, write everything down and then evaluate if it is worth the while.

In the future, focus on jobs that clearly state in their vacancy description that they offer a relocation package.

Comment: Don't forget it's always possible to renegotiate things. Call the company and say "I assumed the company would be paying for relocation expenses. I can't afford to. Will the company do it, or reimburse me, or give me an allowance to cover the costs?"

Comment: @DJClayworth absolutely, that's what I meant with "deal with the company", perhaps it is better that I changed it to "negotiate"

Comment: Thank you guys. really appreciate it